# Is there a way to work out all the required dependencies but without doing "./configure" - C

Tags: c++, c, autotools, gnu-make

For those who have compiled from source knows how much of a pain it is to run "./configure" only to find that X library or missing, worst yet it spits out a silly line saying a cryptic lib file is missing, which you then have to go to a web browser type in the missing file cross you fingers that Google can find the answer for you...

I find that very repetitive, so my question is:

Is there a way to work out all the required dependencies but without doing "./configure"

Comment: Use aptitude or some other package management software.

Comment: I realize that, however I prefer to install from source...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that there's no mention of a specific pkg has been mentioned, I assume this is a generic "how to avoid using configure" question. From a source tarball, no there is no automated way to work the dependencies out. That's what configure is for (you can always read the Makefiles and autoconf files and understand the dependencies manually, but then you'll miss configure very quickly). To avoid it, you need use something other the straight tarball, which has already worked out the dependencies.

For example you can switch to building source rpms (or debs, dependending on your system). Or you can use a system such as Gentoo which is really good at working out the dependencies for you. But all of these require the pkg you're interested in to be available in their format, so they won't work for tarballs that you download from the source provider.

Answer (score 5):

Read the README* or INSTALL* files in the source distribution, if there are any, or look for any documentation on the website where you downloaded it from.  If the package is well documented, dependencies will usually be listed somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Read `configure.ac`/`configure.in`. Look for calls to `AC_CHECK_LIB`, `AC_CHECK_LIBS`, `AC_SEARCH_LIBS`, `AM_PATH_*` (some old packages that don't use `pkg-config` put their checks into the `AM_*` namespace for some reason), `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` (for `pkg-config`), `AX_*` (many autoconf-archive macros are written to check for uncommon dependencies) and any macro call that start with an odd name (i.e., not `AC_*`, `AM_*` or `AX_*`. Try `grep '^[^A]'`?).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do that would be good for the community is to submit a bug report/feature request to the package maintainers.  There are quite a few packages whose configure script does not abort on the first missing dependency, but runs to completion and then prints a summary of all the dependencies that are missing.  That greatly reduces the tedium you describe.  Unfortunately, "quite a few" translates to less than .00001 percent (this is a made up statistic).  If you can convince the package maintainers to re-write their configure script to support this behavior, you will contribute to making the world a better place.

Good luck with that!